# create array of string builder instead of string

Tags: c#, string, stringbuilder

I am creating an application in window application using c#. I have a string array,and its value will be updated in each timer tick event. later on ,i have to convert this array into object array. I know, if we are modifying string many times,it can be time consuming to create new string objects.so i want to use stringBuilder.

let say, in timer tick event:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
     n[i] = i.ToString();
  }
```

where n is the string array and i want to use stringbuilder instead of array.
is it possible? how do i do this? how do i convert stringBuilder type to object type?

Comment: If you want to convert into an object array, why are you converting to string first? Why not just use objects?

Comment: @MatthewWatson He means a non primitive, non value (reference type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a `StringBuilder` here. A StringBuilder is only called for when processing (usually: concatenating) a single string many times. You have many small and unrelated strings.

What you probably want is to replace the array `string[]` with a `List<string>`.

Comment: I have to call this string array many times,program will run for 1-2 days continuously,and array will be called each timer tick.

Comment: You do not 'call' strings. If the code executes `s += ..;` for the same `s` many times, then use an SB.

Comment: @mahua22 Which makes no difference, you still do not need a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your array of strings and use a `StringBuilder` in the loop.

```
var myValues = new String[100];

void tick() {
 var sb = new StringBuilder();

 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  sb.append(i.ToString());
 }

 myValues.add(sb.ToString());
}
```

This adds all values in the range of 0 to 10 to one string. I don't know why you'd need this, so if you want to do something different you should clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
 StringBuilder obj=new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
          obj.append(i.ToString());
      }
```

Comment: its creating a long long string. i want to store it as array. at each timer tick,value of each index will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach that does not need to use an array or `StringBuilder` and which should be efficient enough if the sequence is not too large:

```
string nums = String.Join("", Enumerable.Range(0, 10));
```

However, `string.Join` is really efficient if the input is already an array. In this case it might really be more efficient to use a `StringBuilder`:

```
string nums =  Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
    .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (a, b) => a.Append(b))
    .ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use code something like :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dic = new Dictionary<int, StringBuilder>();

        //Initialize dictionary
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            dic.Add(i, new StringBuilder());
        }

        TimerElapsed(dic);

        TimerElapsed(dic);

        Process(dic.Values.ToArray());
    }

    public static void Process(object[] objects)
    {
        //Do your processing
    }

    public static void TimerElapsed(IDictionary<int, StringBuilder> dic)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            dic[i].Append(i.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Such code will give you benefits of collection and flexibility (for eg: you could convert to array easily)